# cleaner alphabet array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm creating an array of alphabet letters.. It's cluttering the code and doesn't look too good for readability. Does PHP have a cleaner way or a function that already returns the alphabet in an array?

```
array ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g'..........................................);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function which is used to create an array containing range of elements:

```
$alpha = range('a', 'z');
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/j73NH)

Comment: Awesome, didn't know you could do this!

Answer (score 4):

Just so no one has to attempt it, you can also do the same with capital letters:

```
$alpha = range('A', 'Z');
```